# The same variable should be used in all univariate expressions being plotted

Tags: python, numpy, plot, sympy

I am using python 2.7.12 with SymPy 1.0, along with PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3.

I have an expression that corresponds to the following code:

```
x, y = symbols('x y')
f1 = 2*x
f2 = 2*y
F = f1 + f2
```

What should be the syntax to plot this ? I used all sorts of `plot(F)` or `plot3d(F)` , but keep getting the "ValueError: The same variable should be used in all univariate expressions being plotted."

Comment: Did you try `sympy.plotting.plot3d(F, (x,-1,1), (y,-1,1))` ?

Comment: @Stelios: This is an answer, no comment.

Comment: after i try that, i get ValueError: The TextBackend supports only expressions over a 1D range

Comment: @borgmater According to the Sympy's [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#module-sympy.plotting.plot), you should install `matplotlib` if you want 3D plots.

Comment: After struggling with the `matplotlib` installation, I've managed to get it to work, used the `plot3d(F)` function and it did the job ! Ty for your help :)

Comment: Another way to do this is to use `plot_implicit`